# How to find the highest count of sequential (numbers|increasing|decreasing) in pandas DataFrame column of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How to find the highest count of sequential occurrences such as same number, increasing value or decreasing value in the same column.

so given something like:

```
            h_diff  l_diff  monotonic
timestamp                            
2000-01-18     NaN     NaN        NaN
2000-01-19    2.75    2.93        1.0
2000-01-20   12.75   10.13        1.0
2000-01-21   -7.25   -3.31        0.0
2000-01-24   -1.50   -5.07        0.0
2000-01-25    0.37   -2.75        1.0
2000-01-26    1.07    7.38        1.0
2000-01-27   -1.19   -2.75        0.0
2000-01-28   -2.13   -6.38        0.0
2000-01-31   -7.00   -6.12        0.0
```

the highest value of monotonicity for positive values in h_diff is 2 and for negative values it is 3. same for l_diff. so given a rolling of 10 or n, how would i find the highest monotonic count while still being able to change the window size dynamically?

this gives me the 1.0 value for the monotonic column: lambda x: np.all(np.diff(x) > 0) and lambda x: np.count_nonzero(np.diff(x) > 0) will count the total count of 1.0 for the window but what i am trying to find is the longest run in a series of a given window.

---

What I am hoping for is something like:

```
           h_diff  l_diff  monotonic
timestamp                            
2000-01-18     NaN     NaN        NaN
2000-01-19    2.75    2.93        1.0
2000-01-20   12.75   10.13        2.0
2000-01-21   -7.25   -3.31        0.0
2000-01-24   -1.50   -5.07        0.0
2000-01-25    0.37   -2.75        1.0
2000-01-26    1.07    7.38        2.0
2000-01-27    1.19   -2.75        3.0
2000-01-28    2.13   -6.38        4.0
2000-01-31   -7.00   -6.12        0.0
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Just added it in the question. basically a running count that resets when the value goes negative when counting positives or resets when the value goes positive when counting negatives.

Comment: what happend if h_diff is 0 in any value?

Comment: How many series do you want to finally generate? Do you also want to get where h_diff is less than 0 and do the same? ----> 0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,1 for negative values in h_diff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html).

**Initial DataFrame**

```
            h_diff  l_diff
timestamp                 
2000-01-18     NaN     NaN
2000-01-19    2.75    2.93
2000-01-20   12.75   10.13
2000-01-21   -7.25   -3.31
2000-01-24   -1.50   -5.07
2000-01-25    0.37   -2.75
2000-01-26    1.07    7.38
2000-01-27    1.19   -2.75
2000-01-28    2.13   -6.38
2000-01-31   -7.00   -6.12
```

---

```
h = df['h_diff'].gt(0)
#h = np.sign(df['h_diff'])
df['monotonic_h']=h.groupby(h.ne(h.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).where(h,0)
print(df)
            h_diff  l_diff  monotonic_h
timestamp                             
2000-01-18     NaN     NaN            0
2000-01-19    2.75    2.93            1
2000-01-20   12.75   10.13            2
2000-01-21   -7.25   -3.31            0
2000-01-24   -1.50   -5.07            0
2000-01-25    0.37   -2.75            1
2000-01-26    1.07    7.38            2
2000-01-27    1.19   -2.75            3
2000-01-28    2.13   -6.38            4
2000-01-31   -7.00   -6.12            0
```

---

```
df['monotonic_h'].max()
#4
```

---

**Detail**

```
h.ne(h.shift()).cumsum()

timestamp
2000-01-18    1
2000-01-19    2
2000-01-20    2
2000-01-21    3
2000-01-24    3
2000-01-25    4
2000-01-26    4
2000-01-27    4
2000-01-28    4
2000-01-31    5
Name: h_diff, dtype: int64
```

**UPDATE**

```
df = df.join( h.groupby(h.ne(h.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
               .to_frame('values')
               .assign(monotic = np.where(h,'monotic_h_greater_0',
                                          'monotic_h_not_greater_0'),
                       index = lambda x: x.index)
               .where(df['h_diff'].notna())
               .pivot_table(columns = 'monotic',
                            index = 'index',
                            values = 'values',
                            fill_value=0) )

print(df)
            h_diff  l_diff  monotic_h_greater_0  monotic_h_not_greater_0
timestamp                                                               
2000-01-18     NaN     NaN                  NaN                      NaN
2000-01-19    2.75    2.93                  1.0                      0.0
2000-01-20   12.75   10.13                  2.0                      0.0
2000-01-21   -7.25   -3.31                  0.0                      1.0
2000-01-24   -1.50   -5.07                  0.0                      2.0
2000-01-25    0.37   -2.75                  1.0                      0.0
2000-01-26    1.07    7.38                  2.0                      0.0
2000-01-27    1.19   -2.75                  3.0                      0.0
2000-01-28    2.13   -6.38                  4.0                      0.0
2000-01-31   -7.00   -6.12                  0.0                      1.0
```

Comment: WOW! That is an awesome piece of pandas wizardry. It totally works and I have no idea why. It's probably going to take days of research to understand it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do the trick of finding the sequential occurrences of positive or negative number. Code below is for column `h_diff`

```
df1[df1.h_diff.gt(0)].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum().value_counts().max() #sequential occurrences greater than 0

df1[df1.h_diff.lt(0)].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum().value_counts().max() #sequential occurrences less than 0
```

Comment: Thanks. when i run that i simply get a return of 1. any ideas why?

Comment: It is working for me just fine. I get 2 when i rung the first line & 3 when i run the second. I changed the values & checked as well & it is working fine. Make sure the DF name & the column name are correct when you run it.